# What does [*]+ mean in Regex?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to work through the puzzles on regexcrossword.com and I'm finding that it's not clear in its instructions.
My understanding of this expression is:

`[]`= any combination of the characters within the brackets

`*`= 0 or more of the preceding pattern

`+`= 1 or more of the preceding pattern

But, I don't see how there's a pattern to be followed at all. What am I missing here?

Comment: Hint: What's inside the brackets?

Comment: The subtlety you're missing is that the quantifiers (`*`, `+`) lose their special meaning when they're inside square brackets, because the `[...]` always matches *exactly one* character.

Answer (score 7):

`*` means just that character when it is inside `[]` (`+` would as well).

So `[*]+` means *one or more `*`s*.

Answer (score 3):

Usually the brackets are used to note a group of accepted characters, e.g. `[ax]` for `a` or `x` and `[1-9]` as short for the range `[123456789]`. Sometimes they are used or required for masking otherwise used characters. That depends on the used 'dialect' of regex.

In this case `[*]` most probably masks `*` and thus is to be interpreted as `*+`, whereby `*` is to be taken literally while `+` has the meaning you described (1 or more).